# How to drop rows in a Dataframe if any of the cells in that row under a column is not a float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which there are 4 columns. Now, the values stored under these columns are all strings. I want to convert them all to float. Occasionally, I might come across a cell where there is a string under a particular column, in which case I would just want to drop the whole row. For instance, consider the following data frame:

```
   A.    B.    C.    D 
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    1.    3s    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    4s    3.    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
```

As you can see row 2 under colC contains a value which cannot be converted to float, in which case I want to drop all of second row. And same with column B row 4, I want to drop the. whole row.

So the output I want is:

```
   A.    B.    C.    D 
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
   1.    1.    3.    7
```

where i have dropped the second and fourth row, because they contained values which could not be converted to floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the optional parameter `errors='coerce'` to convert all the columns to `numeric` type, then use [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop the rows which contain `NaN` values (as invalid values will be set as `NaN`):

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
    A.   B.   C.  D
0  1.0  1.0  3.0  7
2  1.0  1.0  3.0  7
4  1.0  1.0  3.0  7
5  1.0  1.0  3.0  7
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! When I tried this, I seem to have still some strings left under one of the columns. And when I try to run df1["column_name"], the type I get is object.

Comment: @user1234 hmm.. this should work as all the values that could not get cast to numeric type are converted to `NaN`.  Can you provide sample of the data where you are facing this problem?

Comment: Ahh! The problem seems to go away once I save the above line of code into another variable. I wasn't aware that df1.apply does not alter the dataframe itself.